# unable to control line-in level in 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I'm able to use the command `pactl load-module module-loopback` and the same with unload-module to toggle line-in on and off but there's no way of controlling the level Nothing I adjust in alsamixer has any effect except that if I change the value of channel from 2ch to 4ch that mutes all sound With an audio cable plugged into line-in there's a significant buzz too with nothing connected to the other end of the cable Beyond that I'm trying to play an untested old messed up electric guitar where moving the pots makes sound go on and off probably because of dirt inside them